# Django - How to add pagination in DetailView

Tags: django, pagination, django-views

I am a student and new to Django. How can I add pagination in the detail class view?

Here's my views.py

```
class AuthorDetailView(NeverCacheMixin, generic.DetailView):
model = Author
paginate_by = 1
```

and the pagination code that I used, which is not working.

```
{% if is_paginated %}

          {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
          {% endif %}

          {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if page_obj.number == num %}
              <a class="btn btn-dark mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
            {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
              <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}

          {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
          {% endif %}

            {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass ListView rather than DetailView, and override get_queryset to get the Lectures from the Partner. You can add the Partner object in get_context_data as well if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the first line in the template `{% if is_paginated %}`: you don't seem to pass this variable into template's context. See the [Paginator docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view).

And one more thing: there's no "pagination included" in a `generic.DetailView`, you should use [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview).

In rest, you pretty much nailed it.

[More on Django's doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view).

Comment: sorry if i ask too much question. I'm new to django. I already use listview for author list. once i click one author then i see many book under his name. Is it okay to use another listview just to paginate his works? and how I'm i gonna do that?

Comment: So, you want a "detailed view" of the author, but a "list view" paginated of his books. There are 2 ways: 1) Use a `DetailView` for the author page and manually paginate his books, passing it to the context and render it the template. 2) Use a `ListView` to get the pagination, but you need to override the `get_queryset` and return it based on the author passed in the `url`. And you need to add the author in the context to render it in the template.